# Как лучше реализовать таксономию

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, codeigniter, breadcrumbs

буду краток:
У меня есть таблицы с нодами (моими статьями), файлами (к этим статьям). Конечно теперь не хватает организации, таблицы с тегами(терминами).

Как я решил это сделать:

При обращении сайтэкземпл.ком/алиас

Производить поиск в таблице алиасов(которые в данный момент есть у статей) чтобы сопоставлять их с id сущностей к которым они принадлежат, ну и конечно предотвратить создание термина и ноды с одинаковым алиасом. Вариант не айс но другого не придумал, пришлось создавать колонки nid и tid. Еще был вариант в один столбец, присваивать на перед идентификатор мол начинается с 1 значит статья с 2 тег))

далее получив id ноды или id термина (ну мол обращение к статье или к целой категории) в 1 варианте иду выводить конкретную статью а к ней подтягиваю из таблицы зависимости где есть столбцы id ноды и список id терминов к ней, во втором на оборот обращаюсь к таблице сопоставления в колонку списка терминов и ищу совпадения и по ним получаю соответствующие термину(или нескольким терминам) ноды для вывода с последующей пагинацией.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно это реализовать чтобы делать поменьше лишних движений, так как это мой первый опыт в данном деле. Еще планировал из этих терминов строить категории, хлебные крошки...
Спасибо!

Comment: Какой-то друпал у вас получается. :-) Если это обычный сайт, то после получения адреса сайтэкземпл.ком/алиас (это get-запрос) идет роутинг, где и определяется необходимая «сущность» для вывода. То есть алиас должен быть в базе и быть уникальным (иначе будет несколько сущностей). Отсюда получаете его id (автоинкремент) и дальше уже идёт sql-запрос по вытягиванию данных для вывода. Если хотите разобраться с таксономией, то поизучайте её устаройство в WP. Там она довольно простая.

Comment: Все не так плохо, я уже создал группы роутов и разделил их по типам запросов... Меня конкретно интересует логика действий, реализация какого-то оптимального принципа. Я просто не могу отказаться от некоторых таблиц так как это единственный способ указать связь и при этом учитываю что терминов у статей может быть много, хоть и не обязательно. Спасибо посмотрим как это сделано в WP

Comment: Тут же смотря какая задача. :) Вообще, если вы уж решили через таксономию делать, то вначале с ней досконально разберитесь, иначе потом путаница возникнет. Нужно как можно точнее определить связи между таблицами/объектами и лучше их на бумаге оформить. :)

Comment: Таки я на бумаге и делаю. Просто мне казалось что данные задачи уже кем-то решены и уж точно качественнее чем у меня. А почему через таксономию... Потому как это удобнее, ведь ее легко менять в будущем.